# cublasSgetrsBatched error in kernel

Tags: kernel, cublas

I would like to solve a linear equation with CuBLAS using cublasSgetrsBatched function.
Here is my program :

```
__global__ void invokeDeviceCublasSgemm(cublasStatus_t *returnValue,
                                        int n,
                                        const float *d_alpha,
                                        float *d_A,
                                        float *d_B,
                                        const float *d_beta,
                                        float *d_C)
{
    cublasHandle_t cnpHandle;
    cublasStatus_t status = cublasCreate(&cnpHandle);

    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        *returnValue = status;
        return;
    }



    int indice = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
            {
                d_A[i*5+j] = 1;
            }else
            {
              d_A[i*5+j] = 0;
            }
            d_A[i*5+j] = indice++ +1;
        }
        d_B[i] = i*i+2;
    }




    //A*At

    float alpha = 1.0;
    float beta  = 0;
    int devIpiv = 5;
    int info;



    cublasSgetrsBatched(cnpHandle,
                CUBLAS_OP_N,
                5,
                1,
                &d_A,
                5*5,
                (&devIpiv),
                &d_B,
                (#VERSION1)5, or (#VERSION2)1,
                &info,
                1);


    printf("info %d ",info);


    cublasDestroy(cnpHandle);

    *returnValue = status;
}
```

This function generate  for the first version of cublasSgetrsBatched #VERSION1

```
  info 0 !!!! device to host memory copy error
```

I can't copy the data but there is no info error.

In the version 2 #VERSION2:

```
 info -8
```

I don't understand how to make this function work on a simple linear equation.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you reformat your code so we can read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have several problems.

1. According to [the doc of `cublasSgetrsBatched`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#cublas-lt-t-gt-getrsbatched), the type of your `d_A` and `d_B` should be `const float* []` and `float*[]`, but you use `float*`.
2. The condition `ldb>=max(1,n)` fails for #VERSION2.
3. `devIpiv` should be an array not a scalar.
4. matrix in `d_A` should be LU factored, but you give an arbitrary one. You are suppose to call [`cublasSgetrfBatched`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#cublas-lt-t-gt-getrfbatched) to do LU factorization before this function. Here is [an example code (with performance issue but working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731103/cublas-matrix-inverse-much-slower-than-matlab) to solve `AX=I`, you could use as a reference to solve `AX=B`. You could read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) to see why LU factorization is required.
5. Same performance issue as the example code.